# I'm trying to produce multiple xml files using xslt from one input. its working very well with the batch file but not working in the C#

Tags: c#, xslt

```
    Uri schemaUri = new Uri(Folder+"\\XmlOutput.xml");
    Uri xslUri = new Uri(Folder+"\\SplitStory.xslt");
    Processor processor = new Processor();
    XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(schemaUri);
    XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(xslUri).Load();
    transformer.InitialContextNode = input;
    // BaseOutputUri is only necessary for xsl:result-document.
    transformer.BaseOutputUri = xslUri;
    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
    //var _file = File.Create(Folder+"\\1.xml");
    //serializer.SetOutputStream(_file);
    //serializer.SetOutputFile(Folder + "\\1.xml");
    transformer.Run(serializer);
   // _file.Close();
```

This is the code I'm using for the conversion.

```
       <xs:output method="xml" name="xml" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xs:preserve-space elements="text"/>


    <xs:template match="node()|@*">
        <xs:copy>
            <xs:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xs:copy>
    </xs:template>

   <xs:template match="story">
        <xs:variable name="Self" select="child::Story/@Self"/>
       <xs:variable name="M" select="concat('Story_',$Self,'.xml')"/>
        <xs:variable name="filename" select="concat('output/',$M)"/>
        <xs:result-document href="{$filename}" format="xml" method="text">
            <xs:copy>
            <xs:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
            </xs:copy>
        </xs:result-document>
    </xs:template>
```

This is the xslt i'm using. I've tried the method="text" in the result-document but it's not working

Comment: So you are using the .NET version of Saxon 9 I think. Which version exactly?  And what happens if you say "not working", do you get any error messages, which ones exactly for which statements? By the way, the separator character in URLs is `/` not `\` so putting a backslash in a URL is not a good idea. Also I don't understand the comment of trying `method="text"`, as your code seems to copy XML elements like `match` elements. Please explain in more detail which output you want to create.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I'm using the .net version of Saxon 9.5 Enterprise Edition. It's not giving any error. Your asking about the "output\" right, it is to produce the output xmls inside that output folder. It's working fine with the combination of Saxon jar and batch. By saying its not working I meant that the n number of output XMLs are not able to produce using the c# code I'd mentioned. But the c# code processing other XSLTs which doesn't have result-document and giving the correct output. I've seen in one of these threads that using the 'method="text"' may solve the problem, that's why I tried it.